# typed function using ambient declaration says: is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, ambient

Here is the situation:

I have an old third party javascript function and I want to use it in my typescript codes simply using ambient declaration:

```
old.js: (is loaded by <script> in my .aspx file)
function myFunc() {
    return “Hello World”;
}

typing.d.ts:
export declare function myFunc(): string;

app.ts
import { myFunc } from “./typing”
let str: string = myFunc()

transpild app.js:
var str = typing_1.myFunc();
```

---

There is no issue in compile time but in runtime I get this error:
**‘myFunc is not a function’**

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why would expect that to work. It does not typecheck for one thing. The syntax isn't even valid.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Could you please be more specific? What would be the correct option?

Comment: What I mean is (1) since the variable is not exported, why would importing it work? (2) `declared` is not a keyword (3) since the code is in `./old.js` how would importing from `./typing` load it at runtime (file name needs to align)

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for your comments. It was a typo, actually I just made a simple example out of a big file. Anyway I applied your first and second notes and also updated the question to answer your third comment. Still same issue

Comment: Yes. That is correct

Comment: Then what you are doing makes no sense since it doesn't _export_ a function the code will fail. It defines a global so just import for the side effect `import './old'; myFunc()` which will create the global, and then use it. Also, your the code shown will always fail because the `.d.ts` file has to match the name of the actual file you are loading at runtime (i.e. `old.d.ts`) or it will always fail.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks a lot. Two questions: 1) What do you mean by " import for the side effect import './old';"? 2)Should I put the old.d.ts in the same folder that old.js reside?

Comment: (1) it means an import statement that declares a dependency on some code just to ensure that code is run. `old.js` exports nothing so we can't import it, but we need its side-effect (declaring a global variable) to happen before we use it. (2) yes for the same reason as (1), we need that code (old.js) to be loaded. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @AluanHaddad Excellent. I renamed typing.d.ts to old.d.ts and put it in the same folder where old.js resides, and it worked. Please write an answer to my question then I will pick it as the correct one.

Comment: And one more question. How to change old.js to export myFunc and then how to import it by the consumer?

Comment: How you modify the `.js` depends on your setup, what module format you are using, etc. The declaration file would change to `export declare function myFunc(): void`. At that point, why not rename the file to `old.ts`?

Comment: 1) I use "sysem" module format and the target is "es5" 2)Because I need to type so many interfaces and classes in the old.js so I need .d.ts

Comment: SystemJS handles module syntax (`import`/`export`). So you can just use `export function myFunc(){...}` in `old.js`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks. Waiting for your separate answer thread :)

Comment: Sorry, but IIRC I've answered this question before I think. Glad I could help but I don't want to spam.

Comment: Ok. I will add an answer to help readers out who are chasing the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many appreciate @AluanHaddad for his comments toward fixing the issue.
Here is the answer:

Need to rename typing.d.ts to old.d.ts and put it in the same folder that old.js resides. This is due to the old.js just includes global and doesn't have any export